# Reaching limits of Apache Storm

Tags: apache-storm, low-latency, stream-processing

We are trying to implement a web application with **`Apache Storm`**.

Application
**receives** a huge load of ad-requests (**`100 TPS`** - a hundred transactions / second ),
**makes** some simple calculation on them and then 
**stores** the result in a NoSQL database
 with a **maximum latency of 10 ms**.

We are using **`Cassandra`** as a sink for its writing capabilities.

However, we have already overpassed the **`8 ms`** requirement, we are in **`100ms`**.

We tried to minimize the size of buffers (Disruptor buffers) and to well balance the topology, using the parallelism of bolts.

But we still in **`20ms`**.

With 4 worker ( 8 cores / 16GB ) we are at **`20k TPS`** which is still very low.

Is there any suggestions for optimization or
are we just reaching the limits of `Apache Storm`
(limits of `Java`)?

Comment: Can you explain me why do you need a latency of 10ms? is another system supposed to read from Cassandra and do something with the result?

Comment: Well, the best is that storm send the result to a remote server. This could be done otherwise by having another internal server that reads data from Cassandra and send it it to this remote server. But that data should be already in Casandra, at most 10ms after the request received.

Comment: then you have your answer, storm should send the data directly to the system whom is supposed to consume it ( and to cassandra if you want to store it for other reasons). This will allow you to cut one step in your critical low latency system.

Comment: The total latency between Storm receiving requests and sending it is already more 20ms, with a limited throughput. We need need to reach 100 TPS with latency less then 10ms for 99% of tuples.

Comment: @RadhwaneChebaane did your Project architecture formally pass a principal feasibility test? I come from **transaction flow** processing, **where nanoseconds count**. Having about a **10 ms latency is relaxing, if proper architecture was designed. Poor architecture will suffer and choke and drop flow & performance even at these low-intensity TPS levels**

Comment: The project has been pushed further since, but the problem was not totally solved with Apache Storm. The reason is that the "Lmax awaits" and the buffers strategy are costly and takes a lot of processing time in our usecase. Moreover, blocking sinks connections (external database) are not well managed in high concurrency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the platform you're using, but in C++ **`10ms` is eternity**. I would think you are using the wrong tools for the job.

Using C++, serving some local query should take under a microsecond.

Non-local queries that touch multiple memory locations and/or have to wait for disk or network I/O, have no choice but taking more time. In this case parallelism is your best friend.

You have to find the bottleneck.

1. Is it I/O?
2. Is it CPU?
3. Is it memory bandwidth?
4. Is it memory access time?

After you've found the bottleneck, you can either improve it, async it and/or multiply (=parallelize) it.

Comment: This is a very interesting advice but it doesn't look as a full solution. Do you know some alternatives to Apache Storm (or any open-source distributed streaming enguine) that handles very well I/O ?

Answer (score 2):

There's a trade-off between low latency and high throughput.

If you really need to have high throughput, you should rely on batching adjusting size of buffers bigger, or using Trident.

Trying to avoid transmitting tuples to other workers helps low latency. (localOrShuffleGrouping)

Please don't forget to monitor GC which causes stop-the-world. If you need low-latency, it should be minimized.

Comment: I have already tried these options, I minimized LMAX buffers and used LocalGrouping. Batching will introduce additional latency so it should be avoided. The GC is the main problem as it's interfering so much and we can't control it.

Comment: If workers are under Full GC longer than expected, no further tunings make sense. Please tune GC to resolve Full GC issue before resolving another issues.

Comment: We discovered that Storm is not well adapted to milliseconds latencies because of bolts transfer cost.